# Voice of the verb 'cancel'

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Voice of the verb *cancel*

The sentence below comes from More Word Smart:

> We’d better hire some extra security for the concert; it’s going to be
>   teeming with hopped-up kids, and they’ll be furious when they find out
>   that the main act ***canceled*** last night.

In this sentence the verb *cancel* seems a bit awkward in terms of voice.
To my sense of English grammar *canceled* would be a lot better if it were to be replaced with *was canceled*.

And the dictionary check-up proves my theory, that is, the verb *cancel* almost always used as transitive verb except used in a very limited sense, as in, *two opposing forces that canceled out*.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: It's idiomatic as originally stated.  "Cancel my reservation" means I don't want to have that hotel room/airplane seat reserved for me.  When a theatrical/musical act "cancels" it means that it has declared that it will not appear.

Comment: The question clearly shows its research, looking up dictionaries etc., and yet someone has voted to close this as “offtopic” (“This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center”) on further grounds that it doesn't show research. Sigh.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR  On a site dedicated to linguists, checking for an intransitive use of 'cancel' in various dictionaries may be expected here. And ELU requires that results of research be shown. // Macmillan gives an appropriate example.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR There's no hedged way to say that's incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When did this become “a site dedicated to linguists” BTW? I don't remember it as one. Is there a meta discussion about it?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR It's been part of the mission statement as long as I've been a member. Check at the Help Center. / You now do agree that the intransitive use **is** correct, I take it. You've withdrawn your incorrect comment. This makes the Macmillan example obviously relevant and needed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes I deleted my comment because the crux of the misunderstanding in the question is not about intransitive versus intransitive, but the fact that “main act” is being used as the agent of the action, not the patient. The OP already says “ the verb cancel almost always used as transitive verb…” so was aware of the intransitive use in certain cases, but this did not appear to be one of them (as without that understanding of “main act”, there did appear to be an object/patient that got cancelled, the main act). I think it's a good question.

Comment: The question asks about the word 'cancel'; it may well need editing, but as yet it hasn't been. '... the verb cancel almost always used as transitive verb except used in a very limited sense, as in, two opposing forces that canceled out.' emphasises this. But, as the Macmillan reference and the answers here that echo this show, this is incorrect. // You agree that ELU is aimed at linguists rather than at those with more basic questions?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Putting myself in the OP's shoes: when I read the sentence unaware that “act” is used metonymically, I find it odd not to find “the main act *was* canceled”. The natural question this raises is whether this usage of “cancel” is one of those interesting ones as in your nice answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/107292/77). That is what is asked. The answer is surprising: the issue isn't with the verb but with the noun. It is a good example of a usage question being cleared up. If the question is edited in light of the new understanding, there is no more a question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth At the Help Center I see the site “is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts” and AFAIK there are more of the last. It says questions on word choice and usage and on “grammar” are welcome, and the question happens to fall into those categories IMO, and (under its assumptions) isn't a too-basic one. Interesting that *“Your order has shipped”* got “I don't know why someone downvoted” from you in 2013 (when others considered it too basic), and now a similar question (except that the answer happens to be very different) got the opposite reaction. :-)

Comment: It is not a question of voice but of transitive/intransitive. *Your 2 o'clock (appointment) canceled* is an example of a common usage of the verb as an intransitive verb.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR  A partial quote is usually a misquote. Yours certainly is. 'I don't know why someone downvoted, 39 - **I'm having quite a job finding corroboration in online dictionaries for the following**.'  [bolding added] vs 'And ELU requires that results of research be shown.' and ' Macmillan gives an appropriate example. ' here. // Note also Clare's comment about what the question should be considered to be about. //  ELL was established for more basic grammar and word choice. Though there too, reasonable research (looking words up in available dictionaries) is expected.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No dictionary mentions the ergative usage of “cancel” (because it does not, AFAIK, exist). So where should a question about an apparently ergative usage of the verb be asked (esp. by someone who doesn't know the term)? What would be appropriate research to show? The Macmillan example you mention is merely “If you’re too busy to see her, I’ll call and cancel” and IMO that has no bearing on the apparent ergativity of the verb here (i.e. apparent without the knowledge that “act” is used as metonym, but that is the *answer* and has no bearing on the suitability of the question).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - So far as I can determine, English isn't ergative.

Comment: Consider that "canceled" is an elided version of "canceled their performance".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR This is an intransitive usage of a normally transitive verb. Which the close-voters seem to agree can be found in Macmillan.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is (part of) the *answer* (and not even the most relevant part). The *question*, based on the interpretation that the main act (performance) got cancelled, asks about why the verb appears to be used ergatively (as in [your answer to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/107292/77)). It seems wrong to decide a question is inappropriate based on what the answer happens to be. This is exactly what I asked in my previous comment: how would you ask a question about an apparent ergative usage of a verb: is it on-topic for ELU, and what research should be shown?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"the main act was cancelled" and "the main act cancelled" have a different meaning.

If someone says "The main act was cancelled last night", then "the main act" refers to the final part of the show/event  and we don't know why it was cancelled.

On the other hand, with "The main act cancelled last night", then "the main act" refers to the **headlining performers**, rather than the final stage of the event, and we know that it was cancelled **because the headlining performers cancelled it**.

Eg, from https://www.theguardian.com/music/2009/dec/04/liam-clancy-dies-obituary

> Their appearance on the television programme, in early 1961, when their two-song slot was extended to 15 minutes **after the main act cancelled**, made them famous.

Comment: See also *cancel on* as in *I was going to go to the movies with Jane and John, but they cancelled on me at the last minute.*

Comment: As a musician, I'm pretty confused by the distinction between the "headlining performers" and the "final part of the show". When are they not the same thing? In other words, to me "the main act" always refers to the same band/artist regardless of the voice of the verb "cancel".

Comment: @ToddWilcox this may be specific to theatre rather than concerts, but you can see a part of a show referred to as "the third act" for example.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've definitely been to concerts where the headlining performer wasn't the last act but had one more act coming after them. It's not the norm, but it definitely happens.

Comment: I go to many events where the main act is not the final one. But I think the main point of Todd's comment was the last sentence, that the "main act" always refers to the same artist, and so the distinction drawn in the answer is confusing. "We don't know why it was cancelled" is also redundant (since we're not told that in either case). In both "the main act was cancelled" and "the main act cancelled", it's the same thing that got cancelled and we don't know why it was cancelled. In the latter, we know who did the cancelling. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 16):

Your confusion is understandable, but doesn't stem from the verb.

The verb *cancel* is indeed used in the active voice, and it is used correctly.

The action was performed by the subject that is mentioned in the sentence, that is, *the main act*.

In this case, *the main act* refers to whoever was booked to perform, be it the artist, the orchestra, whatever.

If the main act *was canceled*, someone else did the cancellation: the venue could have canceled the act, the management could have canceled the act. But in this case, *the act* themselves canceld the concert. So simply said, the artist called and said they would't be there.